# Application not taking up full window

Tags: r, shiny

When I run my application, either from R or from Window Explorer, my app uses roughly half of the space of the window. When I see others' apps running, theirs seem to take up the full screen. This causes my widgets and side panels to be sometimes be cramped.

For example, if I use a basic main panel and right side panel, the app looks like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9cmG.png)

As you can see, there is so much extra room to the right of the panel.

Did I accidentally change some setting? If so, how do I fix it?